# Work retreat... with murderers!

Tags: story-identification, movie

I think I saw this film around 10 years ago, not entirely sure of the time, but I believe it was a DVD so was probably a bit older anyway.

It starts off with a bunch of work colleagues on a bus heading to a work retreat, they get to the edge of a forest and there's a tree blocking there path but a creepy path into the forest that heads in the right direction (the usual stuff y'know?). So they head down this other path and come to a building they believe is the retreat, it's falling to pieces and what not.

I think when they get there someone tries out the diving board on the pool and it breaks and they fall into the horrible water. On the first day of activities they are paint balling and someone get's a leg trapped in a bear trap and they have an extra figure running around but no one knows who it is.

That night, I think, one of them get's captured and tortured and they all start to run away. At this point they make it to the actual retreat where the boss says something about having waited for them. The murderers come out the trees and so he fires a rocket launcher at them, it's heat seeking and directs at a plane instead however.

Not sure what happens next but I believe at one point two girls are saved from a hole trap in the ground, someone uses a flame thrower and I think someone get's their head chopped off and recognises that it is chopped off, referencing an earlier joke.

I think it ends with three people escaping on a boat, a man and two women.

Comment: It's not really science fiction, though, is it ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff I couldn't remember who the murderers were. I thought they were zombies at one point when I was remembering it and they turned out to be mentally ill psychopath ex soldiers. Might not be sci-fi but because I couldn't remember enough about that part I thought it might fit.

Comment: It features people wanting to spend time in the woods with their co-workers. I would argue that is an element of fantasy.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Since it's a movie, [movies.se] would've been a sure bet for on-topic whether it was Sci Fi or not.

Comment: @jpmc26 I always forget about that one but I agree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Severance (2006)

The forest, paint ball, bear trap and someone losing their head are all in [Severance](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0464196/). I don't recall any of the rest, but I'm pretty sure you're looking for this.

Comment: Looking at the trailer it also seems to match a lot of the other stuff I said as well though I may have mixed some of it up with another film. Seems to be it though!